# MATLAB - How to implement this Optimization?

Tags: matlab, regression, mathematical-optimization

I am following a text and wish to implement a portion of the code in MATLAB, however I do not understand how to do it. It's goal is to optimize an array of values which will better predict the output based upon some input.

Here is the function:

[image]

I have already implemented the L function. Whilst I understand that 'd' means a very small change, I am unsure exactly how to implement this in MATLAB. Do I need to specifiy this value? If so the change can only go in one direction?

For background, here is the paper: http://www.ee.kth.se/php/modules/publications/reports/2006/IR-EE-SB_2006_026.pdf Page 4 has this particular formula.

Comment: For a scalar theta, this would be easy: `[ L(theta + delta) - L(theta) ] / delta`. As a last resort I think you could get derivative of `L` by using `fminbnd` or some other maximization method.

Comment: read through the article; as I understand, you wish to find the theta where L(theta) has a minimum? Matlab has exactly that tools - `fminbnd` and `fminsearch` - the first has bounded thetas. Would this be an option for you?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your are implementing Newton's method for optimization of multidimensioanl function http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method_in_optimization, though your formula is different from what is given in that link. Anyway, the term in square brackets is inverse of Hessian, which itself is a matrix of second partial derivatives of your cost function L. The final term is the gradient, which is a vector of first partial derivatives of your cost function L. You need to implement both gradient and Hessian as separate functions, which may not be easy. Then instead of taking the inverse of Hessian and multipliying by gradient, you can just use the backslash operator in Matlab: `inv(A)*x` is equivalent to `A\x`.

Comment: Your article explicitly states that this is a Newton's minimization, so I suggest you double check the formula, especially the sign in front of the inverse Hessian.

Comment: Agree, you need to calculate the derivative analytically by hand, and write the code according to your derivation.